# AD account frequently locks and getting authentication error when connecting via RDP

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, remote-desktop, rdp

AD account is locked out frequently even after unlock.

Also Received error message 'an authentication error has occurred code 0x80004005' when connecting via RDP. Please help with the steps to fix both the issues. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> **AD account gets locks frequently**

To fix the issue, please refer this [Article](https://diginetworks.co.in/fixed-ad-user-account-is-frequently-getting-locked-out-what-should-i-do/).

> **To fix the error "an authentication error has occurred code 0x80004005", has different workarounds.**

**Workaround 1:**

- Create a new remote desktop file and launch **`mstsc.exe.`**
- Save the **`default.rdp`** file to your desktop
- Open the **`Default.rdp`** file in Notepad.
- Search for **`authentication level:i:2`** and change it as **`authentication level:i:0`**
- To disable credential support, add **`enablecredsspsupport:i:0`**
- Save the file in Notepad and use the **`default.rdp`** to connect to remote desktop Computer.

**For reference :** [Fix: An Authentication Error Has Occurred (Code: 0x80004005) – Remote Desktop (becomethesolution.com)](https://becomethesolution.com/an-authentication-error-has-occurred-code-0x80004005-remote-desktop#:%7E:text=Fix%3A%20An%20Authentication%20Error%20Has%20Occurred%20%28Code%3A%200x80004005%29,a%20workaround%2C%20disable%20authentication%20using%20a%20new%20)

**Workaround 2 :**

This error `"an authentication error has occurred code 0x80004005"` might occur because of improper patching on TLS levels of RDP servers.

**For reference :** [How to fix the error “an authentication error has occurred(code 0x80004005)” when connecting through RDP. – Ebin Issac](https://ebinissac.me/2019/01/16/how-to-fix-the-error-an-authentication-error-has-occurredcode-0x80004005-when-connecting-through-rdp/)

Comment: Workaround 1: works !!